# Get kafka record timestamp from kafka message

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

**I want the timestamp at which the message was inserted in kafka topic by producer.**

And at the kafka consumer side, i want to extract that timestamp.

```
class Producer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    writeToKafka("quick-start")
  }
  def writeToKafka(topic: String): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9094")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key", "value")
    producer.send(record)
    producer.close()
  }
}



class Consumer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    consumeFromKafka("quick-start")
  }
  def consumeFromKafka(topic: String) = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9094")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    props.put("group.id", "consumer-group")
    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
    while (true) {
      val record = consumer.poll(1000).asScala
      for (data <- record.iterator)
        println(data.value())
    }
  }
}
```

**Does kafka provides a way to do it? Else i will have to send an extra field from producer to topic.**

Comment: `data.timestamp` should give you the timestamp. However, I am not fully sure what time it is... time of producing, time of kafkastoring in broker, time of acknowledging back a successfull produce...

Comment: Yeah, I think Mike is right. There should be a timestamp. It's possible that it would be under headers.timestamp. Not sure about your structure. I'd guess data.headers.timestamp but I'm not sure

Comment: What does this timestamp mean? Epoch seconds or epoch millis?

Answer (score 5):

Kafka provides a way since v0.10

From that version, all your messages have a timestamp information available in `data.timestamp`, and the kind of information inside is ruled by the config "message.timestamp.type" on your brokers. The value should be either `CreateTime` or `LogAppendTime`.

Before this version, you'll have to implement it by hand, usually through modifying your data structure.

Comment: It should be noted that the timestamp is inserted by the producer at the time the `ProducerRecord` is created: it can be either the local epoch time of the producing system (the default) or it can be customized by the application to something more domain specific (e.g. if synthesizing records from data obtained from multiple sources, it could be the latest timestamp of source data).